# Merge or synonymize [indentation], [indent], [autoindent]

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup-request

[indentation](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/indentation) exists with 60 questions. The content is pretty uniform;  all about indentation issues in text editors, so I think it's a useful tag.

That said, there are a couple of variations of the tag that seem to be paired with it frequently:

- [indent](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/indent): 17 questions
- [autoindent](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/autoindent): 26 questions

Any questions with these tags are just as well served by the [indentation](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/indentation) tag. I think they should be synonymized with [indentation](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/indentation), but I don't have any rep for these tags, so I can't suggest this through the normal channels. Could someone please make this happen?

If you have any reputation from [indentation](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/indentation), you can suggest these synonyms [here](https://superuser.com/tags/indentation/synonyms).